# JavaScript before leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a confirmation before user leaving the page. If he says ok then it would redirect to new page or cancel to leave. I tried to make it with onunload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function con() {
    var answer = confirm("do you want to check our other products")
    if (answer){

        alert("bye");
    }
    else{
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onunload="con();">
<h1 style="text-align:center">main page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But it confirm after page already closed? How to do it properly?

It would be even better if someone shows how to do it with jQuery?

Comment: ha ha ha...Yes,that's quite right..but luckily it not my site...my client asking to do it on his side

Comment: Ya, but I am really happy to see those alerts when I am about to quit an unsaved Gmail page.

Comment: Note, on Firefox 4+ only a default message is displayed instead of your custom message https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload#Notes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes)

Answer (score 404):

`onunload` (or `onbeforeunload`) cannot redirect the user to another page.  This is for security reasons.

If you want to show a prompt before the user leaves the page, use `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

This will just ask the user if they want to leave the page or not, you cannot redirect them if they select to stay on the page.  If they select to leave, the browser will go where they told it to go.

You can use `onunload` to do stuff before the page is unloaded, but you cannot redirect from there  (Chrome 14+ blocks alerts inside `onunload`):

```
window.onunload = function() {
    alert('Bye.');
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  alert('Bye.');
});
```

Comment: That's right. You cannot return false from `onunload`. That was a typo. However, what you are doing is returning a string, not a Boolean. For that you'll have to `confirm()`.

Comment: @Joseph: When you return a string from `onbeforeunload`, the browser puts that string into its own confirmation box.  Using `confirm` is useless in `onunload` and `onbeforeunload`, because only the browser can control where it goes, not you.  Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3kvAC/

Comment: @Rocket: Tested it all, and you're absolutely right. Thanks! I guess "you learn new things every day"...

Comment: @Joseph: `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` are kinda weird.

Comment: This worked really well for me +1

What I did was the following: in the text area, set an onkeyup listener, and set a boolean to true when the user changed the textarea. Then in this method, check that boolean, return "You have unsaved changes" and the browser handles the alert.

Comment: so to confirm i cannot have a popup message if they leave the page that has a link in it that they can click? ie a facebook share?

Comment: @Dan: You can check a variable inside the `onbeforeunload`.  Like: `if(!facebook){ return '...'; }`.  Then just add an extra handler to the share button to toggle the `facebook` variable.

Comment: Just a note, if you want to conditionally display a message in `onbeforeunload`, `return false` will make the browser show "false" in a dialog. You need to `return undefined` if you want to let the window close with no user alert.

Comment: This solution works great. In my case I added a conditional return, depending on if the save button is enabled or not. This lets me know if anything was changed:

        if ($('#id_save_button').attr('disabled') != 'disabled'){
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave without saving?';
        }

Comment: Kinda off topic.. My IDE complains that the return is inconsistent, wants the return at the bottom of the function. What does JavaScript best practices say?

Comment: @radtek: Usually with `onbeforeunload`, I do `if(abc){return 'you wanna leave?';}`.  If you want to try to make the IDE happy, you can try `var ret; if(abc){ ret = 'you wanna leave?'; } return ret;`.

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox 45.0.2 and it is not showing the string `"Are you sure you want to leave?"`. Instead, a default message appears: `"This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved"`. Do you know how I can make Firefox display my manual message?

Comment: @Adam: Firefox decided to disallow customization of that message.  That's part of the browser, so you cannot override that behavior.  Other browsers may also be removing the ability to customize the message.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RocketHazmat Chrome has, too. It now only says: **Do you want to leave this site?** Changes you made may not be saved.

Comment: @programmer5000 It's good because some malicious websites can show some useless warnings (for example "You can't leave without giving your bank information")

Answer (score 41):

This code when you also detect form state changed or not.

```
$('#form').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize()); // On load save form current state

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
    if($('#form').serialize()!=$('#form').data('serialize'))return true;
    else e=null; // i.e; if form state change show warning box, else don't show it.
});
```

You can Google JQuery Form Serialize function, this will collect all form inputs and save it in array.  I guess this explain is enough :)

Comment: any idea why this would not work ? Could it be overwritten by other js functions/jquery plugins ? I'm running a webrtc app and I would like to "close" some stuff when the client closes the window thus the need to handle the window close.

Comment: this can be overwritten by any other plugin etc, mostly developer made mistake with selector, if you are doubted about overwritten, put your jquery code before close of </body> tag.

Comment: Yes... if you have some JS code that hides or disables input fields after the page has been loaded then when you do the check to compare the hidden\disabled fields won't be serialized. The check will fail of course. ;) There's this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4748748/114029

Comment: By the way... there's a better way here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16322042/114029

Comment: This is so smart! Thank You! Also for others, don't forget to execute it after the document is ready!

Comment: should be noted that this will also rise a warning when pressing the submit button. one could serialize the form again on click of the submit button to prevent that.

Comment: @Adam I have not yet seen that issue

Answer (score 30):

This what I did to show the confirmation message just when I have unsaved data

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (isDirty) {
    return 'There is unsaved data.';
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

returning `undefined` will disable the confirmation

Note: returning `null` will not work with IE

Also you can use `undefined` to disable the confirmation

```
window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
```

Answer (score 22):

This will alert on leaving current page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye; 

</script>
```

Answer (score 12):

In order to have a popop with Chrome 14+, you need to do the following :

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'my text';
});
```

The user will be asked if he want to stay or leave.

Comment: Any idea why this is not working ? I'm using chrome ( latest version) along with a bung of jquery plugins but I don't get any alert when when I close the window.

Comment: @hey Why the down vote ? It's working.... You need to make sure it's outside of the `jQuery(document)` and I suggest to put it right after all your plugins are loaded. Also, this snippet doesn't do any alert... it's only a demo with `return`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the following one-liner to *always* ask the user before leaving the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = s => "";
```

To ask the user when something on the page has been modified, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476717/3498950).

Comment: does this also fire if i refresh the page or just exit?

Comment: Yes, it will fire on a refresh or exit.

Comment: Is there anyway to know when it is refresh vs when its first time?

Comment: When a user comes to the page first time as oppose to the user refreshing the page.

Comment: Oh, no. It won't be fired when a user comes to the page for the first time. Only when closing or changing pages or refreshing.

Comment: Awesome... Thank you. So the first time I can use another function.

Comment: I can't get this function to trigger when the user clicks the back button. I've read around and it seems that it's no longer possible to interfere with the functionality of the back button. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

Most of the solutions here did not work for me so I used the one found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

I also added a variable to allow the confirm box or not

```
window.hideWarning = false;
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    if (!hideWarning) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = '';
    }

});
```

Comment: When user refresh the page browser refresh button this time
 ``Blocked attempt to show a 'beforeunload' confirmation panel for a frame that never had a user gesture since its load.`` this error occur any suggestion

Answer (score 5):

Normally you want to show this message, when the user has made changes in a form, but they are not saved.

Take this approach to show a message, only when the user has changed something

```
var form = $('#your-form'),
  original = form.serialize()

form.submit(function(){
  window.onbeforeunload = null
})

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  if (form.serialize() != original)
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">

<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    return "Write something clever here...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit more helpful, **enable** and **disable**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload.myPluginName', false); // or use function() instead of false
$(window).off('beforeunload.myPluginName');
```