# Is it possible to display modalbox , Only if user click on close tab/browser button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a share box . my requirement is to display a bootstrap model box , if and only if user click on the close tab/browser button . if its possible how ?

**HERE IS MY CODE which is not working  :**

```
var unhook=0;
 jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if(!unhook){
    var message = "Why are you leaving?";
    $("#myModal4").modal();
    console.log(e);
    // e.returnValue = message;
    // return message;
 }
});

$(function () {
  $("a").click(function {
    var unhook=0;
  });
});
```

NOTE: I don't want to show simple alertbox , I have to display a modelbox where user will put the review . that's why my question is different

Comment: Yes it's possible!

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144545/show-pop-up-on-browser-tab-close-or-leave-the-page) Please see this

Comment: i have seen this @ShahidRafiq i don't want to display alert box/confirm box etc before my model box

Comment: @Pugazh , How ? can you share me some exemple ?

Comment: @Pugazh share me some link where i can see how its work , by the way i am not looking for simple alert box , looking for modelbox or ecuvalent

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can only display the canned dialog box which your browser supports.

The reason is mainly security: Imagine a malicious JavaScript which doesn't allow you to leave the page or close the browser. That's why a browser terminates all JavaScript on the page when you close the tab or the browser.

Some browsers allow you to display a message in a dialog box but not all. For details, see: [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Comment: then is there any solution to identify the user who's going to leave the site ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onclick="showModal()"></buton>
<div id="bootstap-modal-id">

</div>
```

Then

```
function showModal(){
  alert('something');
  $('#bootstap-modal-id').modal();
}
```

try this ! Happy coding :)

Comment: i think you havnt read my question properly . its not normal button . i m asking for close tab button .

Comment: I can see your code first, because i answered your question before your edit . in click event you can correct "function()" .