# javascript style alert with link before user navigates away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking at having a alert style box show up when a user tries to leave the page but I what I wanted to do is have a share link in the alert style box

I have read this ticket [javascript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page) and now am unsure if this is possible.

I realise this will run

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
 alert("hi");
});
```

Now I know you cannot add links to an alert window so am trying to get round this another way but cant think of how i would display a alert/popup before going to another page that has a link in

Can anyone suggest anything - is there a plugin that might do this?

Comment: So you need to show a link in `alert box`?

Comment: you cant see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Comment: so dev its not possible?

Comment: Its better you not do even if u do a hack as if you find a bug and use it to do it one they they will fix it and you will be again at same point. This is a security risk suppose i want to close a tab and in code you opne new popups or do malicious things???? So browserts dont allow it. If user wants to go they are allowed u can use standard window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
} if you like

Answer (score 1):

Its better you not do even if u do a hack as if you find a bug and use it to do it one they they will fix it and you will be again at same point. This is a security risk suppose i want to close a tab and in code you opne new popups or do malicious things???? So browserts dont allow it. If user wants to go they are allowed u can use standard

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return 'You have unsaved changes!'; }
```

if you like So try this. istead of custom things.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/xN3kL/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add links to an alert window. What you could do is use a jQuery Plugin like http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default and call it within `beforeunload` function.

HTML

```
<div id="dialog" title="My Link">
 <a href="#">My Link</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

OR if don't want to use jQuery you could use a `window.open`
eg: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Comment: according to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own it is not possib;e