# Jquery Catching clicking of links outside a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to catch the event when a user clicks a hyperlink outside of a specific `div` element. To demonstrate :

If I have this HTML :

```
<a id = "1" href="/someurl..">link</a>
<a id = "2" href="/someurl..">link</a>
<a id = "3" href="/someurl..">link</a>

<div id="content">
   <a id = "4" href="/someurl..">link</a>
</div>
```

I need to catch the event where the user clicks every hyperlink outside of the `div` with `id` of "content". But ignore the event when the links inside the `div` "content" is clicked.

**------------------UPDATE----------------**

Someone suggested I include what i'm trying to achieve to add clarity. And what the best way to do this is the question.

My use case is that, I have a div where some operations (links) such as sort, edit etc is being utilized. While links outside are links that redirects to other pages. I want to make a confirm modal using bootbox if a user navigates away. I could use the unload but it also fires when I click on the edit,sort operations (links inside the div).

Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case here, why are you doing this?

Comment: my use case is that, I have a div where some operations (links) such as sort, edit etc is being utilized. While links outside are links that redirects to other pages. I want to make a confirm modal using bootbox if a user navigates away. I could use the unload but it also fires when I click on the edit,sort operations :)

Comment: You may want to include that info in the question. There are loads of ways to do what your asking, some may be better than others given the specific situation.

Comment: This may be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page

Comment: I've also tried that but as ive mentioned it kinda 'mistakes' other links inside the div content because they still unload the page. It does the job, but I want it to be selective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `siblings()` method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to target specifically the siblings of your `div` element:

> **`.siblings( [selector ] )`**
>
> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$('#content').siblings('a').on('click', function() { ... });
```

Comment: this is by far the cleanest!, but i'll give upvotes to other answer because they too are correct thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `.not()` operator or `:not`.

```
$('a').not('#content a').click(function(){
    //...do something
})
```

Comment: content is an ID :)   #content  not .content

Comment: woops! sorry!  Good catch

Answer (score 3):

use `:not()`

```
$('a:not(#content a)')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xs54qwcm/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways. One way

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        if($(this).closest('#content')){
            return;
    }
});
```

`closest` checks if there is a parent element with id content.