# Javascript funtion to ask before leaving window of if status is true

Tags: javascript

I have a activestatus var which tells whether saving to file are done or not, if file is not saved activestatus will be true in that case if user presses browser back or tries to type different url and go he should get a pop up saying "You have not saved changes you want to save? yes no".

here is what I tried so far

```
var activeInput=true;
 window.onbeforeunload =checkNow;

    function checkNow(){
        if(activeInput==true){
            alert('please save your changes');
            return "Do you want to leave?"
        }else{
            alert('gonow');
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Basically I want to call a function only when user wants to leave the window and saving to file is not done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Comment: based on variable I want to call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7080269/215552

Answer (score 2):

Try using `addEventListener`, and use `e.returnValue` to show the message.

```
var activeInput=true;

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', checkNow);

function checkNow(e) {
        if (activeInput === false) return true;
        var message = "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Ensure you save any changes.";
        e.returnValue = message;
        return message;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8o3cjtg/). You can read more about the `onbeforeunload` event, including the behavior of `e.returnValue` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere please mark it correct if it worked for you.

Comment: its saying wait 5minutes so I am wating, it says you can accept ans in 2 minutes

Comment: the message you have written is not getting called, its calling default message, and also it is running when my activeINput is true.

Comment: How can I capture yes/no result input which user pressed? there is no if and else case in your code, it just reloads at all cases, major problem is I have save button and on click of save button also it reloads.