# launch confirm dialog if user changes input without saving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement in JS a warning if a user changes an input field in a form without saving. The expected behavior is that I make a change into the input and if I try to close the window the confirm dialog appears.

However, what actually happens is when I close the window, the window closes and the dialog does not appear.

I'm referencing the following resources:

[Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes)

[JavaScript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

This is what I have currently:

```
var formInputChanged = false;
$(function() {
    // activate modal is field is edited
    $(".account-settings-form input").on("input", function() {
        window.formInputChanged = true;
    });
    $("input[value='Cancel']").click(function() {
        window.formInputChanged = false;
    });

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
        if (window.formInputChanged) {
            confirm("You have unsaved changes");
        }
    });
 });
```

I have that variable set globally so as far a I understand, should be fully accessible and I'm assigning it to the window in the functions.

I can see in the console.log() that `formInputChanged` is the correct value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

> This event enables a web page to trigger a confirmation dialog asking
>   the user if they really want to leave the page. If the user confirms,
>   the browser navigates to the new page, otherwise it cancels the
>   navigation.

What does "leave the page" mean? Back button? X out? Is it an event listener issue?

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an
>   event handler should call preventDefault() on the event.

I have that in place so that doesn't seem to be the issue...

Why doesn't the confirm modal launch?

Here is a full JS Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g6wjrcae/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the conditional you add:

```
event.returnValue = "";
            return "";
```

So:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (window.formInputChanged) {
            event.returnValue = "";
            return "";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in handler for `"beforeunload"`

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if(formInputChanged) {
        var confirmationMessage = "You have unsaved changes";

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    }
});
```

I believe `confirm("You have unsaved changes");` is where your issue is.