# In laravel 8 when bowser or tab is close ask confirmation message

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using laravel 8. when i login and try to close browser or tab then before close I want ask confirmation massage with ok and cancel button. If user clicks ok then logout user if cancel stay on same page.
I have tried javacript beforeunload method but didnot work.as if fire on all button and link click.

in laravel i tried session.php
‘expire_on_close’ set true but not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

Comment: You should not add a confirmation message when a user closes the tab or browser in my opinion. I also doubt it will be possible in most browsers.