# how to add event listener to browser back and refresh button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a confirmation popup on browsers back and reload button. Currently, I am able to show popup only atleast once I have to click on the page. But, I want to show popup when page loaded and without doing anything other If I clicked Back button or Refresh button instead.

It's ok, If solution is in Jquery or Javascript.

Comment: Maybe this from 11years ago suits your purpose:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.