# Disabled fields not picked up by serializeArray

Tags: jquery, serialization

*(Question updated to reflect real issue)*

I just realized that `serializeArray` is not fetching content from disabled fields.

A set of (street) address fields are populated by selecting an item from a `autosuggest` list. Once this is done, the fields are disabled. I could change this to `read only`, but I want the disabled look and feel without having to change CSS.

Is there a way to have `serializeArray` grab data fro, the disabled fields?

**Solution**

Thanks to Mohammad, I created a small plugin that helps me solve my issue:

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gARuJ/))

```
    var form_data = $('form').serializeAll();

    (function ($) {
      $.fn.serializeAll = function () {
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();

        $(':disabled[name]', this).each(function () { 
            data.push({ name: this.name, value: $(this).val() });
        });

        return data;
      }
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: do you have name attribute in your dynamically added element's

Comment: Yes. All input fields that needs to be submitte4d has t he name attribute. Oh, one imporatnt note, the fields are disabled! (sorry - I'll update Q)

Comment: That is the reason why serializeArray doesn't pick those element's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make $.serialize() take into account those disabled :input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748655/how-to-make-serialize-take-into-account-those-disabled-input-elements)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this

```
var data = $('form').serializeAllArray();
```

And here is the small plugin that is used

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.serializeAllArray = function () {
    var obj = {};

    $('input',this).each(function () { 
        obj[this.name] = $(this).val(); 
    });
    return $.param(obj);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

You can also try enabling all your element's just to serialize  them and then disable them after serializing.

```
var myform = $('#form');
var disabled = myform.find(':input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
var serialized = myform.serializeArray();
disabled.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: What would really make the day, was if you moved the `serializeArray` inside the new plugin and concatinated the data there. Then all I needed to do is `data = $('form').serializeAllArray()`.

Comment: @Steven I know its been a couple years, but could you explain the this reference on line 11?  Why do you need that in the select?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut, you now, I can't actually remember how `$(':disabled[name]', this).each()` works. I'm out of shape on my jQuery. Sorry :-/

Comment: @Steven I figured it out.  this is the reference to the form itself.

Comment: @MohammadAdil this handles only the input tags and not select and textarea tags

Comment: It would have been helpful if this answer noted that it returns results in an entirely different format than the function it is designed to replace.

Comment: Also worth noting that inputs in disabled fieldsets are excluded also. Workarond is similar:
`var disabled_fs = $(this).find('fieldset:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
var data = $(this).serializeArray();
disabled_fs.attr('disabled',true);`

Answer (score 20):

you can use `readonly`
serializeArray() can read it.

Comment: Unfortunately `readonly` doesn't work on <select> fields, so that's only an option for inputs and textareas.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior and won't be fixed. Here is a workaround

```
function serializeJSONIncludingDisabledFields (form) {
  var fields = form.find('[disabled]');
  fields.prop('disabled', false);
  var json = form.serializeJSON();
  fields.prop('disabled', true);
  return json;
}
```

Link to the [issue](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/issues/49)

Comment: I have to make it form.serializeArray to make it work for my form.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#field').removeAttr('disabled');
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
$('#field').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

The solution above is better - alternatively you can just remove the disabled attribute from the element, serialize the fields then re-add the attribute.

Comment: The above should use .prop() instead of .removeAttr() and .attr().