# Undefined is not a function, even so a form is found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this handle on a form submit:

```
  $("#my_form").on("submit", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    debugger;

    var data = $("#my_form").serializeAllArray(); //undefined is not a function
    var data2 = $(this).serializeAllArray();      //undefined is not a function

  )};
```

Why am I getting this error **inside** this handler (which means the form is found)? I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: search 'serializeAllArray' in your jquery library included.

Comment: I think its `.serializeArray()`

Comment: jQuery object doesn't have `serializeAllArray` method, it's `serializeArray`. Where have you seen such method?

Comment: [maybe this is where it's come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15958900/1238344)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the function is:

[`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) instead of `.serializeAllArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Use serializeArray() instead of serializeAllArray(). May be serializeAllArray method is not present in your jquery library.

Comment: What additional value does your answer provide compared to the already  existing answer?

Comment: When I came to answer it there was no answer. But after I post my answer, I saw that.

Comment: Ok, that's understandable, although I'm a bit surprised that it took you 20 min to write this answer. Tip: before submitting an answer, especially such a short one, refresh the page to see if someone else didn't already post it.

Comment: My net connection was gone for the time. Sorry....