# $('#myDiv :input') - collects everything but not one disabled field?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I make a

```
var fields = $('#myDiv-:input').serialize();    
alert(checkoutFields);
```

this collects me all the inputs in `myDiv` but not the one input that is `disabled`(?)

how can I collect ALL inputs?

Comment: `:input` select all inputs but `serialize()` doesn't accept `disabled` input. Because `disabled` input shouldn't send.

Comment: @Mohammad .. hi, thanks for the response :) .. but how can I achieve that the `disabled`-fields get serialized, too?

Comment: [How to make $.serialize() take into account those disabled :input elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748655/how-to-make-serialize-take-into-account-those-disabled-input-elements)

Comment: HA! DUDE! . thank you very much :)