# javascript value in input post method to php not working

Tags: php, jquery

one input in my form is completed by a variable javascript. I do not understand why my php code does not see this variable? (if I enter the value manually, it will work)

```
 <?php $kwota2 = $_POST['kwota2']; // undefinded kwota2 ?? ?>

    <form action="post>
    <input id="kwota2" type="text" name="kwota2" disabled>

    <script>
           $("#kwota2").val(localStorage.getItem('sumalist'));
    </script>
<input type="submit" value="Zamawiam">
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because its marked it as disabled 
convert it into readonly and try

and add your javascript code in document ready function

Comment: I must have security that this input can not be edited.

Comment: @A.Jo Nothing on the client side is secure. You need to do validation on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first method. You will serialize objects that are `disabled` with jQuery.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var data = $('form').serializeArray();
  $(':disabled').each(function(i, item) {
    data.push({
      name: item.name,
      value: $(this).val()
    });
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="post">
  <input id="kwota2" type="text" name="kwota2" value="example" disabled>
  <input type="submit" value="Zamawiam">
</form>
```

The second method is to add the readonly property.The only difference between `disabled` and `readonly` is `readonly` **serializable**.

```
<form action="post">
  <input id="kwota2" type="text" name="kwota2" value="example" readonly>
  <input type="submit" value="Zamawiam">
</form>
```

**Also :** [How to make $.serialize() take into account those disabled :input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748655/how-to-make-serialize-take-into-account-those-disabled-input-elements)